# 3.4 mainline kernel: external storage is no longer automounted

Tags: 12.04, kernel, hard-drive

I have just updated my kernel from 3.2 to 3.4 precise, so, after restarting ubuntu, i tried to connect my external hard or usb storage but isn't mounted. Also, i check the output of `#fdisk -l` command, but i can not find my usb storage / external hard label there. This is the output of `#fdisk -l` :

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048      255999      126976    6  FAT16
/dev/sda2   *      257040   262437839   131090400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       262437840   337252544    37407352+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       337252606   976771071   319759233    f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       337252608   431521964    47134678+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       431522028   576267614    72372793+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       576273538   826046234   124886348+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda8       826046464   842045439     7999488   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda9       842047488   900638719    29295616   83  Linux
/dev/sda10      900640768   976771071    38065152   83  Linux
```

I also check the output of `#lsusb` but my external hard name appears there, this the output of lsusb command :

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6416 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bc2:5031 Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex USB 3.0 <--
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 413c:8161 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:8162 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad [Synaptics]
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 413c:8160 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 365 Bluetooth
```

How do i do to solve my problem ? It is the serious problem for me, help me to solve. 
Thanks for your attention and sorry if it duplicates with another thread!

**EDIT**

```
[ 1928.674377] show_signal_msg: 27 callbacks suppressed
[ 1928.674390] unity-2d-shell[3041]: segfault at 329 ip 00007fe4cef80dd7 sp 00007fff19d68420 error 4 in libQtDBus.so.4.8.1[7fe4cef4f000+7b000]
[ 2018.282180] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 2029.593959] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[ 2762.789721] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd
[ 2793.794120] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 4184.355678] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 4200.064570] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci_hcd
[ 6736.417629] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
[ 6748.266537] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
```

These lines are the output for `#dmesg | tail` command. I can not find the usb device with label starting `sdb`!

**EDIT 2**
The output for command `#ls /dev` is as follow ;

```
autofs           mcelog              sda2      tty25  tty58      ttyS31
block            mei                 sda3      tty26  tty59      ttyS4
bsg              mem                 sda4      tty27  tty6       ttyS5
btrfs-control    net                 sda5      tty28  tty60      ttyS6
bus              network_latency     sda6      tty29  tty61      ttyS7
cdrom2           network_throughput  sda7      tty3   tty62      ttyS8
cdrw2            null                sda8      tty30  tty63      ttyS9
char             oldmem              sda9      tty31  tty7       uinput
console          port                sg0       tty32  tty8       urandom
core             ppp                 sg1       tty33  tty9       usbmon0
cpu              psaux               shm       tty34  ttyprintk  usbmon1
cpu_dma_latency  ptmx                snapshot  tty35  ttyS0      usbmon2
disk             pts                 snd       tty36  ttyS1      v4l
dri              ram0                sr0       tty37  ttyS10     vboxdrv
dvd2             ram1                stderr    tty38  ttyS11     vboxusb
dvdrw2           ram10               stdin     tty39  ttyS12     vcs
ecryptfs         ram11               stdout    tty4   ttyS13     vcs1
fd               ram12               tty       tty40  ttyS14     vcs2
full             ram13               tty0      tty41  ttyS15     vcs3
fuse             ram14               tty1      tty42  ttyS16     vcs4
fw0              ram15               tty10     tty43  ttyS17     vcs5
hidraw0          ram2                tty11     tty44  ttyS18     vcs6
hpet             ram3                tty12     tty45  ttyS19     vcs7
input            ram4                tty13     tty46  ttyS2      vcsa
kmsg             ram5                tty14     tty47  ttyS20     vcsa1
log              ram6                tty15     tty48  ttyS21     vcsa2
loop0            ram7                tty16     tty49  ttyS22     vcsa3
loop1            ram8                tty17     tty5   ttyS23     vcsa4
loop2            ram9                tty18     tty50  ttyS24     vcsa5
loop3            random              tty19     tty51  ttyS25     vcsa6
loop4            rfkill              tty2      tty52  ttyS26     vcsa7
loop5            rtc                 tty20     tty53  ttyS27     vga_arbiter
loop6            rtc0                tty21     tty54  ttyS28     vhost-net
loop7            sda                 tty22     tty55  ttyS29     video0
loop-control     sda1                tty23     tty56  ttyS3      zero
mapper           sda10               tty24     tty57  ttyS30
```

Comment: So does that mean , it can be mounted in `3.2` kernel version.

Comment: Yes, it can be mounted in `3.2` version of kernel.

Comment: **The mainline kernel builds are explicitly for debugging purposes only, not for everyday use. As such they are unsupported.** If you think this is a kernel issue, please post a message to the [Linux Kernel Mailing List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_mailing_list)

Comment: Why duplicate?!

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to mount your device, but it would have to be done manually each time:

You first find out the device file by viewing the contents of `dmesg`

The easiest way to do this is by reconnecting the usb device and then running `dmesg | tail` which will show you the last ten lines of `dmesg`

You should be able to find a filename along the lines of `sdb1`

Then you can mount the filesystem to whatever directory you like by running

```
sudo mount \dev\sdb1 \your\dir\here
```

Browse to that location in your filemanager and you should be able to access the device

EDIT:
Here's the output from `dmesg | tail` when I plug in my external hard drive:

```
[  895.458054] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Recovered Error [current] [descriptor]
[  895.458067] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[  895.458072]         72 01 04 1d 00 00 00 0a 09 0c 00 00 00 00 00 07 
[  895.458096]         00 00 
[  895.458104] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb]  ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x1d
[  895.645276] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Recovered Error [current] [descriptor]
[  895.645290] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):
[  895.645296]         72 01 04 1d 00 00 00 0e 09 0c 00 00 00 00 00 07 
[  895.645319]         00 00 00 00 40 50 
[  895.645332] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb]  ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x1d
```

`[sdb]` shows me that the device file for this hard drive is `\dev\sdb`

Comment: Please check the Edit for my question. I can not find the [sdb]!

Comment: I've seen the edit but unfortunately am not entirely sure where to go from here. You could try `#ls /dev` to see if there are any device files there named `sdb` or `sdb1` but if it didn't show up in `dmesg` output then I doubt there will be. I'll report back if I find any more useful information though

Comment: I added my system output for `#ls /dev`, and i can not find `sdb` :|